# Can a smooth closed curve's interior be split into smaller copies of itself?

Tags: geometry

Is there a smooth Jordan curve whose interior can be split into any finite number of regions whose boundaries are similar to the original curve?

E.g, a square can be split into four smaller squares, but it is not smooth. A circle is smooth but cannot be split into any number of smaller circles.

Comment: What do you mean by “but it is not continuous”?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The tangent to the curve is not defined at the corners of the square.

Comment: I think you mean "smooth", not "continuous".

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. I do mean smooth.

Comment: So you mean a differentiable curve instead of continuous ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. You may look for a smooth tiling of the plane, that seems just as difficult. I don't know if there is one, but I can imagine that this has been researched.

Comment: If you divide the disk into concentric annuli, aren't the boundaries still circles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose a smooth Jordan curve $C$ existed such that its interior could be divided into regions $D_1,\ldots, D_k$ with the property that $C_i$, the closed boundary of $D_i$ is smooth. Then $C=\cup_{i=1}^k (C_i \cap C)$. Since $D_i$s are disjoint, the arcs $C_i \cap C$ intersect at most at two points. In other words, the arcs $C_i \cap C$ that are nonempty give a partition of $C$. Let $P$ be a point of the partition such that $P\in C_i \cap C_j \cap C$ for some $i,j$. The tangent line to $C_i$ and $C$ are the same and $C$ and $C_i$ are on the same side of the line. Similarly $C_j$ and $C$ have the same tangent line and both $C$ and $C_j$ are on the same side of the line near $P$. So $C_i$ and $C_j$ have the same tangent line at $P$ and both are on the same side of the line. This is impossible for two Jordan curves with disjoint interiors.